# Using install4j with proguard

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, install4j

I have a Spring Boot application which I pack into a `.jar` file.
This jar gets obfuscated by `gradle` task and `ProGuard` library.
 (This part works correctly. I am able to inspect and run the jar.)

Once the obfuscated jar is ready I use `install4j`, include the obfuscated .jar file and make an installer.
After the installation when I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 124 Exception Details:   Location:
    com/bla/test/Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @95: ifeq   Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.   Bytecode:
    0000000: b800 5212 11b6 0057 120f b600 58b6 0053
    0000010: 4cbb 0022 592b 1202 b700 544d bb00 1f59
    0000020: b700 4d4e bb00 1e59 1208 b700 4b3a 04bb
    0000030: 001e 5912 03b7 004b 3a05 1905 ba00 6400
    0000040: 00b6 004c 2d19 04b6 004e 572d 1905 b600
    0000050: 4e57 2c04 b600 552c 2db6 0056 b800 5199
    0000060: 001d b800 503a 0619 062c b600 4fa7 000f
    0000070: 3a07 b200 3112 01b9 0060 0200 a700 00     Exception Handler Table:
    bci [103, 109] => handler: 112

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)     at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)  at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:83)  at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)  at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

I also struggled with getting the obfuscated version of the code.
To get generate the obfuscated `.jar` I used the following config in:

```
-libraryjar 'etc/resources/libs/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.9.9.jar'
-libraryjar 'etc/resources/libs/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.9.jar'
-libraryjar 'etc/resources/libs/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar'
-libraryjar 'etc/resources/libs/jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar'
-libraryjar 'etc/resources/libs/dsl-json-1.9.3.jar'   
-dontnote
-dontwarn
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-dontpreverify
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod,*Annotation*
-keep interface *
-keep public class org.apache.logging.**
-keep public class com.potato.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
-overloadaggressively
-optimizationpasses 3
-allowaccessmodification
```

I am concerned about the `-dontwarn` and the `-dontpreverify` flags. They helped me to pass the build obfuscated jar process but I am quite sure that they are just a workaround.

It is very difficult to debug this process and find out what is going on.
Can anyone point me in the right direction in trying to figure out what is going on with that error?

Comment: Is this really related to install4j? The VerifyError is in your obfuscated main class, it should occur regardless of whether you run it via install4j or with the default Java launcher.

Comment: @IngoKegel - I agree that it is more related to the way which `proguard` does to obfuscate the code rather than install4j. However, the `The VerifyError ` only occurs after generating the installer. As i mentioned before if this class is ran from the IDE this problem does not occur.

Comment: install4j inserts its own main class and calls your main method, so there is a slightly different environment. Maybe try not to obfuscate your main class and see if that helps.

Comment: I think these lines:
`-keep public class com.potato.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}`
proguard config file are excluding the main class from obfuscation